# Using KDevelop during development of a shared library

Tags: cmake, kdevelop

I'm trying to use KDevelop as an IDE for development of a C++ shared library. An earlier posts here indicate that I need to edit a CMake makefile for doing that. This is quite painful and very time consuming as it means converting our custom gmake-oriented build system into something of CMake.

Is there any other way for doing that?

Answer (score 2):

KDevelop doesn't force you to use a specific buildsystem like many other IDEs do. CMake is just the default as it's very well integrated and many if not all KDE projects use cmake.

You can use a different build system by choosing "Custom Buildsystem" or "Custom Makefile Project Manager".

Custom Makefile Project Manager simply calls "make" - your current build system should work this that.